# Stack elements at the bottom (instead of the top) of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `<ul>` that has a fixed height and I need the `<li>`'s inside it to stack at the bottom (instead of the top).

I tried `vertical-align: bottom` on the `<ul>` but that doesn't change anything.

The content `li` have a chance of overflowing, and if they do I need the scrollbar to work.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
li {}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbcnvk4s/

Thanks !

Comment: Flexbox is your friend!

Comment: `vertical-align` controls how two (or more) inline or inline-block elements are aligned to each other (it doesn't effect the content inside of an element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try CSS **flexbox**:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;           /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column;  /* align children vertically */
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
}

li:first-child {
  margin-top: auto;        /* shift top li, and all li's beneath, to the bottom */  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Flex [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) are used to align the `li`s to the bottom.

Although `justify-content: flex-end` would also align the items to the bottom, the scroll mechanism doesn't work when the items overflow the container ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u5mka1bp/1/) |  [bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41863033/3597276)).

As an aside, scrolling would work if `justify-content` were `flex-start` or `center` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u5mka1bp/2/)).

Comment: `margin-top: auto` on the first `<li>` is GENIUS ! Works really well, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `position: absolute; bottom: 0`.

https://jsfiddle.net/hbcnvk4s/1/

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute
}
```

Not so easy with `vertical-align`

Comment: This looks right at first glance, but this moves the whole `ul`at the bottom of it's parent div. Unfortunately I can't do that, I need the `ul`to have a fixed height and `li`'s inside of it scrolled down.

Comment: @AlexandreDanault why do you _need_ the `ul` to be fixed height?

Comment: @Chaim I need to have the `ul` on a fixed height because I need the scrollbar to work. With a parent `div` it doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/5tbLc8j3/

Answer (score 0):

you could also use **flex-direction: column-reverse.**

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  /* align children vertically AT BOTTOM */
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```