# Can't get vertical scrollbar with justify-content: flex-end

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a scrollbar problem whenever I use `justify-content: flex-end;`. I disabled the scrollbar how can this be fixed. Hope someone can help me.

### RECONSTRUCTION

```js
$(".input").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    $(".text").append($("<p />", {
      html: $(".input").val()
    }))
    e.preventDefault()
    $(".input").val("")
  }
})

// AUTO INPUT

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".text").append($("<p />", {
    html: "test"
  }))
}
$(".text").append($("<p />", {
  html: "Now we see that the scrollbar works, its now gonna add <b>justify-content: flex-end;</b> than you see the scrollbar disables it self in 6 seconds"
}))

$(".text").scrollTop($(".text")[0].scrollHeight);

setTimeout(function() {
  $(".text").css("justify-content", "flex-end");
  $(".text").append($("<h3 />", {
    html: "justify-content: flex-end; is added and scrollbar is disabled"
  }))

  $(".text").scrollTop($(".text")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 6000)
```

```css
.text {
  height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="text">
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="input">
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug.

There are some workarounds, but they can be hacky and unreliable across browsers.

For instance, in your code, if you reverse the order of content in the HTML, and switch the `flex-direction` to `column-reverse`, you get your scrollbar... *in Chrome* (didn't work in FF or Edge).

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/k3z3wacz/)

Here are a few references that may be useful:

- [Use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36130760/3597276)
- [flexbox justify-content: flex-end breaks scroll](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411624)
- [Bug 962501 - when justify-content: flex-end, overflow auto. when content overflows scrollbars dont show](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=962501)
- [justify-content: flex-end and overflow: auto don't play along](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/53)

Comment: Yikes— in reference to my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503733/overflow-scroll-y-not-working-with-flexbox), is this the only way to "stack" elements in a container?

Answer (score 1):

The same reason when something overflows to the left or top of `body`, you can't scroll to the left or "up" to see the overflow. The point from which you begin scrolling for `body` begins at the top/left `body`. Just like the scroll point for this div begins at the beginning/top of the div. You can't scroll into a negative position in the div, just like you can't scroll into a negative position in `body`.

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
}
.right {
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}
.top {
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: So is there no fix for mine example ?