# Scroll doesn't work when grid item aligned to the end / bottom

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I want to create a chat using `CSS grid` and ran into the problem that I cannot combine `align-self: end;` and `overflow-y: auto;`.

The `ul` holds all the messages and should be aligned to the bottom, so that even when there is only one message, it appears on the bottom.

The header and the footer of the chat are fixed and you only scroll through the messages (like Whats App and similar applications).

I created [**this pen**](https://codepen.io/MichaelZ_dev/pen/oqdoRQ) with some messages. The messages go through the header and it never allows me to scroll.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#chat {
  display: grid;
  height: inherit;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #4081ff;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<section id="chat">
  <header>header</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>last message</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution with scrollbar. I added additional div.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWaRJY

```
<section id="chat">
  <header>header</header>
  <div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>last message</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</section>

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#chat {
  display: grid;
  height: inherit;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
}

header, footer {
  background: #4081ff;
}

#content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug.

### Analysis

You are using `align-self: end` to pin the middle grid item (`ul`) to the bottom of the row. That fails to render a vertical scrollbar.

I tried various alternatives:

1. I made the `ul` grid item a flex container with `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: flex-end`.
2. I made the `ul` grid item a flex container with `flex-direction: column` and applied `margin-top: auto` to the first `li` flex item.
3. I tried switching from

   ```
   grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px
   ```

   to

   ```
   grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px
   ```

Nothing worked. In all cases, the browser failed to generate a vertical scrollbar.

However, in all cases, when there is no "end" alignment (in other words, the grid item is aligned to the default "start" position), vertical scroll works fine.

Because the scrollbar works in "start" but fails in "end", I think it's fair to call this a bug.

Here's the same problem in flexbox: [Can't get vertical scrollbar with justify-content: flex-end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41863033/3597276)

---

### Solution #1: Chrome only

If you make the `ul` grid item a (nested) grid container with `align-content: end`, that seems to work in Chrome, but not Firefox and Edge. I didn't test in Safari, IE11 or other browsers.

```css
#chat {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: grid;
  align-content: end;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #4081ff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="chat">
  <header>header</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>last message</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</section>
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdKJdE?editors=1100)

---

### Solution #2: All browsers

This solution takes advantage of the fact that vertical scroll works fine with items in the `start` position. You can insert another `li` or, even better, a pseudo-element (as they are considered grid items when applied to grid containers). This `li` will be empty and set to occupy all free space, which will pin the actual items to the bottom.

```css
#chat {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; /* applies to the first row, the only explicit row;
                              all subsequent rows, which are implicit rows, will
                              take `grid-auto-rows: auto` by default */
}

ul::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px dashed red; /* demo only */
}

header,
footer {
  background: #4081ff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="chat">
  <header>header</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>Message 1</li>
    <li>last message</li>
  </ul>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</section>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMJQvZ)